# How to format row of excel file based on specific condition in python using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I want to Highlight specific rows in excel file like whenever a specific keyword occurred in any rows, it should highlight that row. 
For example: Open below image and see whenever the word "Weekly Avg" will come in any row, it should highlight that specific row.

**Image:**

[image: click on this link to see image]

**Current coding:**

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = excel_filename)
sheet_obj = wb.active
sheet_obj.delete_cols(1)

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
red_font = openpyxl.styles.Font(bold=True)

for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if 'Weekly Avg' in row:
        for cell in row:
             sheet[str(cell.coordinate)].font = red_font

wb.save(excel_filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below way and successfully ran but I'm unable to do highlight whole row[image: see Image here].

```
col = "ABCDEFG"              # to get column
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = excel_filename)
sheet_obj = wb.active
sheet_obj.delete_cols(1)

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for cell in sheet["A"]:
    if "Weekly Avg" in cell.value:
        for i in range(0, len(col)):
            cell_coordinate = col[i]+str(cell.row)            # create cell ID
            sheet[cell_coordinate].font = openpyxl.styles.Font(color='000000FF', bold=True)
wb.save(excel_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

I tend not to have to rely on hard-coded values for `rows` and `columns` when dealing with `openpyxl` since data is dynamic and can easily change to offset your hard-coded values. While my solution is not perfect, I have tested it on `Python 3.6` and `openpyxl 3.0.6` and it produces the desired output. I believe the logic can be improved to avoid the resource-intensive `for` loops.

I choose to use `Named Styles` since we are applying formats to many `cells` and as per the `openpyxl` `styles` documentation,

> In contrast to Cell Styles, Named Styles are mutable. They make sense
> when you want to apply formatting to lots of different cells at once.

The rest of the Logic should be self-explanatory from the comments.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, NamedStyle


# Define the colors to style the cells
BLACK = "000000"
YELLOW = "FFFF00"

# Define the cell fonts and fills
avg_cell_font = Font(name="Calibri", size=10, color=BLACK, bold=True)
avg_rows_fill = PatternFill(fill_type="solid", fgColor=YELLOW)

# Named style for the average totals rows
avg_totals_style = NamedStyle(
    name="avgTotals",
    font=avg_cell_font,
    fill=avg_rows_fill,
)

# load the workbook
excel_filename = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))).joinpath(
    "averages_test_data.xlsx"
)
wb = load_workbook(filename=excel_filename)

# Register the named style cell formats to the workbook
if avg_totals_style.name not in wb.style_names:
    wb.add_named_style(avg_totals_style)

# get worksheet to apply formats to
ws = wb.active

# get minimum and maximum row numbers with data as strings
first_row_str = str(ws.min_row)
last_row_str = str(ws.max_row)

# get column letters of first and last columns with data
first_col_str = get_column_letter(ws.min_column)
last_col_str = get_column_letter(ws.max_column)

for row_index, row_data in enumerate(
    ws[f"{first_col_str}{first_row_str}:{last_col_str}{last_row_str}"]
):
    avg_total_str = "Weekly Avg"
    avg_totals_check = False
    avg_total_rows = []

    for cell in row_data:
        # check if the cell contains a value
        if cell.value:
            # if any cell contains the "Weekly Avg" string value
            # update the avg_totals_check flag and append that
            # row number to the avg_total_rows list
            if avg_total_str in str(cell.value):
                avg_totals_check = True
                avg_total_rows.append(str(cell.row))

    # if the avg_totals_check flag is True, then
    # iterate each cell in the row number strings in the
    # avg_total_rows list and apply a style to the cells
    if avg_totals_check:
        for row_str in avg_total_rows:
            for cell in ws[f"{row_str}:{row_str}"]:
                cell.style = avg_totals_style.name

# save the workbook
wb.save(filename=excel_filename)
```